# iOS Check Button Pressed Again

Tags: ios, button, state

I have an IBAction on a button - when it is pressed the method runs as expected.

In that method I update the text label of the button that was pressed.

What i want to happen is when it is repressed I'd like to check the label of the button AND the fact that it was repressed, any ideas how? I'm currently trying to check the state:

```
if ([buttonName isEqualToString:@"Done"] && (_airlineSelectButtonLabel.state == UIControlEventTouchUpInside)) {
        //Do whatever
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont see from your question how you retrieved the title on your button, make sure you are using:

```
NSString *strTitleOnButton = [button titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But better use selected property of your UIButton to know if pressed unpressed for example:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.selected)
    {
        //Already Pressed
    }
    else
    {
        //Unpressed
    }
    sender.selected.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Keeping state in a view is a poor idea. The view should be just that views and controls, no state.

Comment: Hi, Yep i get the strTitleOnButton that way already. However when using sender.selected it says it could not find that property?

Comment: Well cast sender to UIButton as ((UIButon *)sender).selected.

Comment: is your header to the IBAction (id)sender or (UIButton *)sender
Set it to be **(UIButton *)sender** or cast it like @Idindu said.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, to get the label of the button use `[[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"Done"];`
inside your button action.

Comment: Liked that!!! I am not new to iOS and that "currentTitle" I didn't get to know, thats good to know!